# Configure SVN on WIndows 8

Tags: windows-8, tortoisesvn

I am new in SVN configuration. I have Windows 8 with 4 drives. I am planing to configure TortoiseSVN 1.7.12 on one of drive and will do the checkout from another drive.

I have installed it but unable to configure it as SVN server.

How can i configure it?

Appreciate you help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get TortoiseSVN configured as a server because it's not a server. TortoiseSVN is a **client**.

If you wish to run a server, you need to acquire & install Apache (if you want to use HTTP access) and a Win32 command-line build of Subversion (no matter what). You may find this easier via one of the pre-built packages such as [CollabNet Subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion), [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/), or [uberSVN](http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn)

If you're going to be sharing with someone else, get a separate server set up and managed properly - don't run it off your desktop (what happens when your hard drive crashes, or you go away on vacation?).

Answer (score 0):

The current stable version of TortoiseSVN is 1.7.13. You might consider using that.

Server configuration is an activity which you should do after careful preparation.
You may read the details here:
http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html